# Cartela de bingo em c

Tags: c#, c, random

Estava resolvendo um exercício da faculdade sobre matrizes e acabei travando.

Ex: Construa um programa para gerar automaticamente números entre 0 e 99 de uma cartela de bingo. 
Sabendo que cada cartela deverá conter 5 linhas de 5 números, gere estes dados de modo que não tenha 
números repetidos dentro das cartelas. O programa deve exibir na tela a cartela gerada.

Eu tentei resolver dessa forma :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define n 5

int main ()
{ 
  int a[n][n],cont;

  srand(time(NULL));

      for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]==-1;
        }
    }
    // Preencher a matriz com valores n repitidos o "do/while" compararia td os valores da matriz e caso tenha repeticao aumemta um contador q executa o looping

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            do
            {   
                cont=0;
                a[i][j]=rand()%99;

                for (int l=0;l<n;l++)
                {
                    for (int c=0;c<n;c++)
                    {
                      if (a[i][j]==a[l][c] && (i!=l && j!=c))
                        cont++;
                    }
                }
             } while(cont!=0);
        }
    }



                for (int l=0;l<n;l++)
                {
                    for (int c=0;c<n;c++)
                    {
                       printf(" \t %d ", a[l][c]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }

return 0;
}
```

Mas não funcionou e não tenho ideia de como resolver.

Comment: includes quais biblioteca?

Answer (score 0):

Username 7873, montei uma função que talvez te ajude. A ideia é NÃO repetir os número nunca. 
   Monto duas listas: Uma lista com todos os números que serão sorteados (essa lista sempre diminui de tamanho com .RemoveAt) e uma lista que receberá os números que já foram sorteados.
   No caso do BINGO são 75 NÚMEROS pois, são 15 números para cada letra! Desta forma: A Letra "B" vai de 1 até 15, a "I" vai de 16 até 30, a letra "N" vai de 31 até 45, a letra "G" vai de 46 até 60 e a letra "O" vai de 61 até 75.
   Depois eu vou RETIRANDO (.RemoveAt) os números de uma lista e sorteando com um número a menos (INDEX) o número interno da array permanece "inalterado" (os que já foram sorteados caem fora...). 
   Detalhe... está em C#, mas acho que você conseguirá ter uma ideia. A função "SORTEIA" receberá sempre 1 número a menos para sortear...

```
public static List<Resultado> SorteiaNumeros(string StrNumero)
{
    List<int> strListaNumero = new List<int>();
    List<Resultado> strLista = new List<Resultado>();
    int intPosicaoSorteada;
    int IntContador = Convert.ToInt32(StrNumero);

    //Pegar todos os números que podem ser sorteados e colocar em uma lista.
    for (int i = 1; i <= IntContador; i++)
    {
        strListaNumero.Add(i);
    }

    // ir retirando os números da lista conforme o INDEX.
    do
    {
        intPosicaoSorteada = Convert.ToInt32(Sorteia(strListaNumero.Count.ToString()));

        strLista.Add(new Resultado
        {
            Posicao = (strLista.Count + 1).ToString(),
            Nome = Convert.ToString(strLista.Count + 1) + " - " + strListaNumero[intPosicaoSorteada - 1] + ".",
            Ordem = strListaNumero[intPosicaoSorteada - 1].ToString()
        });

        strListaNumero.RemoveAt(intPosicaoSorteada - 1);

    } while (strListaNumero.Count > 0);

    return strLista;
}
```

---

```
public static string Sorteia(string StrNumero)
{
    Random randNum = new Random();
    return randNum.Next(1, Convert.ToInt32(StrNumero) + 1).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

eu fiz algumas alterações no seu codigo e parece ta funcionando

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a[5][5], cont, i, j, c, l;

  srand(time(NULL));


    // Preencher a matriz com valores n repitidos o "do/while" compararia td os valores da matriz e caso tenha repeticao aumemta um contador q executa o looping

    for (i=0;i<5;i++){
        for (j=0;j<5;j++){
            do{   
                cont=0;
                a[i][j]=rand()%99;

                for (l=0;l<5;l++){
                    for (c=0;c<5;c++){
                      if (a[i][j]==a[l][c] && (i!=l && j!=c)){
                      cont++;
                      }
                    }
                }
             } while(cont!=0);
        }
    }

                for (l=0;l<5;l++)
                {
                    for (c=0;c<5;c++)
                    {
                       printf(" \t %d ", a[l][c]);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: User158513, sua resposta pode ser útil! porém ajudará mais o autor da pergunta se você  comentar o código com as melhorias realizadas